# Chrome Extension: How to make function work after clearing localstorage?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dragsort

```js
//DRAGSORT PLUGIN
//GO DOWN TO SEE MY CODES

  // jQuery List DragSort v0.5.2
// License: http://dragsort.codeplex.com/license
(function(e){e.fn.dragsort=function(t){if(t=="destroy"){e(this.selector).trigger("dragsort-uninit");return}var n=e.extend({},e.fn.dragsort.defaults,t);var r=[];var i=null,s=null;this.each(function(t,o){if(e(o).is("table")&&e(o).children().size()==1&&e(o).children().is("tbody"))o=e(o).children().get(0);var u={draggedItem:null,placeHolderItem:null,pos:null,offset:null,offsetLimit:null,scroll:null,container:o,init:function(){n.tagName=e(this.container).children().size()==0?"li":e(this.container).children().get(0).tagName.toLowerCase();if(n.itemSelector=="")n.itemSelector=n.tagName;if(n.dragSelector=="")n.dragSelector=n.tagName;if(n.placeHolderTemplate=="")n.placeHolderTemplate="<"+n.tagName+">&nbsp;</"+n.tagName+">";e(this.container).attr("data-listidx",t).mousedown(this.grabItem).bind("dragsort-uninit",this.uninit);this.styleDragHandlers(true)},uninit:function(){var t=r[e(this).attr("data-listidx")];e(t.container).unbind("mousedown",t.grabItem).unbind("dragsort-uninit");t.styleDragHandlers(false)},getItems:function(){return e(this.container).children(n.itemSelector)},styleDragHandlers:function(t){this.getItems().map(function(){return e(this).is(n.dragSelector)?this:e(this).find(n.dragSelector).get()}).css("cursor",t?"pointer":"")},grabItem:function(t){var i=r[e(this).attr("data-listidx")];var s=e(t.target).closest("[data-listidx] > "+n.tagName).get(0);var o=i.getItems().filter(function(){return this==s}).size()>0;if(t.which!=1||e(t.target).is(n.dragSelectorExclude)||e(t.target).closest(n.dragSelectorExclude).size()>0||!o)return;t.preventDefault();var u=t.target;while(!e(u).is(n.dragSelector)){if(u==this)return;u=u.parentNode}e(u).attr("data-cursor",e(u).css("cursor"));e(u).css("cursor","move");var a=this;var f=function(){i.dragStart.call(a,t);e(i.container).unbind("mousemove",f)};e(i.container).mousemove(f).mouseup(function(){e(i.container).unbind("mousemove",f);e(u).css("cursor",e(u).attr("data-cursor"))})},dragStart:function(t){if(i!=null&&i.draggedItem!=null)i.dropItem();i=r[e(this).attr("data-listidx")];i.draggedItem=e(t.target).closest("[data-listidx] > "+n.tagName);i.draggedItem.attr("data-origpos",e(this).attr("data-listidx")+"-"+e(i.container).children().index(i.draggedItem));var s=parseInt(i.draggedItem.css("marginTop"));var o=parseInt(i.draggedItem.css("marginLeft"));i.offset=i.draggedItem.offset();i.offset.top=t.pageY-i.offset.top+(isNaN(s)?0:s)-1;i.offset.left=t.pageX-i.offset.left+(isNaN(o)?0:o)-1;if(!n.dragBetween){var u=e(i.container).outerHeight()==0?Math.max(1,Math.round(.5+i.getItems().size()*i.draggedItem.outerWidth()/e(i.container).outerWidth()))*i.draggedItem.outerHeight():e(i.container).outerHeight();i.offsetLimit=e(i.container).offset();i.offsetLimit.right=i.offsetLimit.left+e(i.container).outerWidth()-i.draggedItem.outerWidth();i.offsetLimit.bottom=i.offsetLimit.top+u-i.draggedItem.outerHeight()}var a=i.draggedItem.height();var f=i.draggedItem.width();if(n.tagName=="tr"){i.draggedItem.children().each(function(){e(this).width(e(this).width())});i.placeHolderItem=i.draggedItem.clone().attr("data-placeholder",true);i.draggedItem.after(i.placeHolderItem);i.placeHolderItem.children().each(function(){e(this).css({borderWidth:0,width:e(this).width()+1,height:e(this).height()+1}).html("&nbsp;")})}else{i.draggedItem.after(n.placeHolderTemplate);i.placeHolderItem=i.draggedItem.next().css({height:a,width:f}).attr("data-placeholder",true)}if(n.tagName=="td"){var l=i.draggedItem.closest("table").get(0);e("<table id='"+l.id+"' style='border-width: 0px;' class='dragSortItem "+l.className+"'><tr></tr></table>").appendTo("body").children().append(i.draggedItem)}var c=i.draggedItem.attr("style");i.draggedItem.attr("data-origstyle",c?c:"");i.draggedItem.css({position:"absolute",opacity:.8,"z-index":999,height:a,width:f});i.scroll={moveX:0,moveY:0,maxX:e(document).width()-e(window).width(),maxY:e(document).height()-e(window).height()};i.scroll.scrollY=window.setInterval(function(){if(n.scrollContainer!=window){e(n.scrollContainer).scrollTop(e(n.scrollContainer).scrollTop()+i.scroll.moveY);return}var t=e(n.scrollContainer).scrollTop();if(i.scroll.moveY>0&&t<i.scroll.maxY||i.scroll.moveY<0&&t>0){e(n.scrollContainer).scrollTop(t+i.scroll.moveY);i.draggedItem.css("top",i.draggedItem.offset().top+i.scroll.moveY+1)}},10);i.scroll.scrollX=window.setInterval(function(){if(n.scrollContainer!=window){e(n.scrollContainer).scrollLeft(e(n.scrollContainer).scrollLeft()+i.scroll.moveX);return}var t=e(n.scrollContainer).scrollLeft();if(i.scroll.moveX>0&&t<i.scroll.maxX||i.scroll.moveX<0&&t>0){e(n.scrollContainer).scrollLeft(t+i.scroll.moveX);i.draggedItem.css("left",i.draggedItem.offset().left+i.scroll.moveX+1)}},10);e(r).each(function(e,t){t.createDropTargets();t.buildPositionTable()});i.setPos(t.pageX,t.pageY);e(document).bind("mousemove",i.swapItems);e(document).bind("mouseup",i.dropItem);if(n.scrollContainer!=window)e(window).bind("wheel",i.wheel)},setPos:function(t,r){var s=r-this.offset.top;var o=t-this.offset.left;if(!n.dragBetween){s=Math.min(this.offsetLimit.bottom,Math.max(s,this.offsetLimit.top));o=Math.min(this.offsetLimit.right,Math.max(o,this.offsetLimit.left))}var u=this.draggedItem.offsetParent().not("body").offset();if(u!=null){s-=u.top;o-=u.left}if(n.scrollContainer==window){r-=e(window).scrollTop();t-=e(window).scrollLeft();r=Math.max(0,r-e(window).height()+5)+Math.min(0,r-5);t=Math.max(0,t-e(window).width()+5)+Math.min(0,t-5)}else{var a=e(n.scrollContainer);var f=a.offset();r=Math.max(0,r-a.height()-f.top)+Math.min(0,r-f.top);t=Math.max(0,t-a.width()-f.left)+Math.min(0,t-f.left)}i.scroll.moveX=t==0?0:t*n.scrollSpeed/Math.abs(t);i.scroll.moveY=r==0?0:r*n.scrollSpeed/Math.abs(r);this.draggedItem.css({top:s,left:o})},wheel:function(t){if(i&&n.scrollContainer!=window){var r=e(n.scrollContainer);var s=r.offset();t=t.originalEvent;if(t.clientX>s.left&&t.clientX<s.left+r.width()&&t.clientY>s.top&&t.clientY<s.top+r.height()){var o=(t.deltaMode==0?1:10)*t.deltaY;r.scrollTop(r.scrollTop()+o);t.preventDefault()}}},buildPositionTable:function(){var t=[];this.getItems().not([i.draggedItem[0],i.placeHolderItem[0]]).each(function(n){var r=e(this).offset();r.right=r.left+e(this).outerWidth();r.bottom=r.top+e(this).outerHeight();r.elm=this;t[n]=r});this.pos=t},dropItem:function(){if(i.draggedItem==null)return;var t=i.draggedItem.attr("data-origstyle");i.draggedItem.attr("style",t);if(t=="")i.draggedItem.removeAttr("style");i.draggedItem.removeAttr("data-origstyle");i.styleDragHandlers(true);i.placeHolderItem.before(i.draggedItem);i.placeHolderItem.remove();e("[data-droptarget], .dragSortItem").remove();window.clearInterval(i.scroll.scrollY);window.clearInterval(i.scroll.scrollX);if(i.draggedItem.attr("data-origpos")!=e(r).index(i)+"-"+e(i.container).children().index(i.draggedItem))if(n.dragEnd.apply(i.draggedItem)==false){var s=i.draggedItem.attr("data-origpos").split("-");var o=e(r[s[0]].container).children().not(i.draggedItem).eq(s[1]);if(o.size()>0)o.before(i.draggedItem);else if(s[1]==0)e(r[s[0]].container).prepend(i.draggedItem);else e(r[s[0]].container).append(i.draggedItem)}i.draggedItem.removeAttr("data-origpos");i.draggedItem=null;e(document).unbind("mousemove",i.swapItems);e(document).unbind("mouseup",i.dropItem);if(n.scrollContainer!=window)e(window).unbind("wheel",i.wheel);return false},swapItems:function(t){if(i.draggedItem==null)return false;i.setPos(t.pageX,t.pageY);var o=i.findPos(t.pageX,t.pageY);var u=i;for(var a=0;o==-1&&n.dragBetween&&a<r.length;a++){o=r[a].findPos(t.pageX,t.pageY);u=r[a]}if(o==-1)return false;var f=function(){return e(u.container).children().not(u.draggedItem)};var l=f().not(n.itemSelector).each(function(e){this.idx=f().index(this)});if(s==null||s.top>i.draggedItem.offset().top||s.left>i.draggedItem.offset().left)e(u.pos[o].elm).before(i.placeHolderItem);else e(u.pos[o].elm).after(i.placeHolderItem);l.each(function(){var t=f().eq(this.idx).get(0);if(this!=t&&f().index(this)<this.idx)e(this).insertAfter(t);else if(this!=t)e(this).insertBefore(t)});e(r).each(function(e,t){t.createDropTargets();t.buildPositionTable()});s=i.draggedItem.offset();return false},findPos:function(e,t){for(var n=0;n<this.pos.length;n++){if(this.pos[n].left<e&&this.pos[n].right>e&&this.pos[n].top<t&&this.pos[n].bottom>t)return n}return-1},createDropTargets:function(){if(!n.dragBetween)return;e(r).each(function(){var t=e(this.container).find("[data-placeholder]");var r=e(this.container).find("[data-droptarget]");if(t.size()>0&&r.size()>0)r.remove();else if(t.size()==0&&r.size()==0){if(n.tagName=="td")e(n.placeHolderTemplate).attr("data-droptarget",true).appendTo(this.container);else e(this.container).append(i.placeHolderItem.removeAttr("data-placeholder").clone().attr("data-droptarget",true));i.placeHolderItem.attr("data-placeholder",true)}})}};u.init();r.push(u)});return this};e.fn.dragsort.defaults={itemSelector:"",dragSelector:"",dragSelectorExclude:"input, textarea",dragEnd:function(){},dragBetween:false,placeHolderTemplate:"",scrollContainer:window,scrollSpeed:5}})(jQuery)




$("#add").click(function() {
    var list1 = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#textarea').val('');
    var newitem = '<p>' +'<span style="color:red;"class="drag">drag</span>' +list1 + '</p>';
    $('#list').append(newitem);
    var list = $("#list").html();
    localStorage.setItem('list', list);
    return false;
  });
  
  if (localStorage.getItem('list')) {
    $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem('list'));
  }
  $("#list").dragsort({dragSelector: ".drag"});
  
   $('#clear').click(function() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
    return false;
  });
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
      <input type="text" id="textarea" />
      <button id="add">Add</button>
      <button id="clear">Delete All</button>
</div>
<div id="list"></div>
```

i am using [dragsort](https://dragsort.codeplex.com/) plugin to drag my list. But if i clear localStorage, dragsort does not work. But if i reopen extension it works.

Also if you look at [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dgeynhck/)  you can see  that drag does not work if you dont press run.

Why this is happening?

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
    var list1 = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#textarea').val('');
    var newitem = '<p>' +'<span style="color:red;"class="drag">drag</span>' +list1 + '</p>';
    $('#list').append(newitem);
    var list = $("#list").html();
    localStorage.setItem('list', list);
    return false;
  });
  
  if (localStorage.getItem('list')) {
    $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem('list'));
  }
  $("#list").dragsort({dragSelector: ".drag"});
  
   $('#clear').click(function() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
    return false;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

When there is no item in `localStorage` you need to reinit `$("#list").dragsort({dragSelector: ".drag"});` when you add first item;

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itzmukeshy7/9ppaxk9w/) for this

Comment: Dude, wanted to ask one more question?After dragging , dragged element is not where i dragged. How can i solve it ?

Comment: do not ask more questions, open a new question